# Why are some requests failing in ZeroMQ Publisher Subscriber Model in JAVA?

Tags: java, akka, zeromq

While Publishers are trying to communicate with subscribers via ZeroMQ, let's say out of every 10 requests, two of them are failing as the subscribers are taking too long at times to prepare the response sent from the publishers' end and send it back. Needed some (architectural) help on how to stop these requests to fail.

Comment: A well documented MCVE would fit in, wouldn't it? Maybe get inspired by how other Members detail their questions so as to get answers helping in their use-case contexts.

Comment: @user3666197 hey thanks for the edit .